# Javascript: unique inner function "remembers" outer function first call arguments?

Tags: javascript, closures

Using this code

```
this.outerFn = function(param)
{
    this.currentParam = param;
    if(!this.hasInnerFn)
    {
        this.innerCallFn = function()
        {
            console.log('param: ' + param.toString() + ' ; this.currentParam: ' + this.currentParam);
        }
        this.hasInnerFn = true;
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        this.innerCallFn();
    },1000)
}
```

and calling:

```
this.outerFn('param 1')
this.outerFn('param 2')
```

gives the following results:

```
param: param 1 ; this.currentParam = param 1
param: param 1 ; this.currentParam = param 2
```

Why at the second call to `innerCallFn` does it reference the outer function's first parameter ?

`innerCallFn` is created only once, so won't it see as `'param'` only its value at the first call ?
In other words, does every function call have its own closure ?

Comment: `this.innerCallFn` is defined only when the outer function is first called so of course it always prints the version of `param` that existed when it was defined.

Comment: @Juhana That is also how i explained, but I was looking for a confirmation of my last question:) later edit : and this is obvious. "Silly" question from me :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `param` used by the inner function is indeed bound just once when that function is first created.